# Fill in values between different start and end values

Tags: r, tidyverse

As the title suggests my issue is the following. I have one variable identifying the beginning of an event and another variable indicating the end time of the same event. I want an variable indicating whether an event took place or not.

```
dat <-
  data.frame(
    "t" = c(1:10),
    "id1" = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 4, NA),
    "id2" = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, 4, NA),
    "desiredoutcome" = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 0)
  )
```

Here, the variable desired outcome would take value 1 whenever it is between the same value of id1 and id2. Consider e.g. row 6. it is both between id =2 and id = 3 and the dummy should hence be 1.
Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Does is need to be any more complicated than checking if both `all` id1 and id2 are non-NA?

Comment: Not really. I want element 7 to be 1 as it is between the two 3's even though both id1 and id2 are NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
#Position of non-NA index in `id1`
inds1 <- which(!is.na(dat$id1))
#Corresponding position of non-NA index in `id2`
inds2 <- match(dat$id1[inds1], dat$id2)
#Initialise the result column to 0
dat$result <- 0
#create a sequence between inds1 and inds2 and assign value as 1.
dat$result[unique(unlist(Map(seq, inds1, inds2)))] <- 1
dat

#    t id1 id2 desiredoutcome result
#1   1   1  NA              1      1
#2   2  NA   1              1      1
#3   3  NA  NA              0      0
#4   4  NA  NA              0      0
#5   5   2  NA              1      1
#6   6   3   2              1      1
#7   7  NA  NA              1      1
#8   8  NA   3              1      1
#9   9   4   4              1      1
#10 10  NA  NA              0      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to easily modify the code to count the number of events taking place instead of the dummy indicating whether it is taking place or not? For example in row 6, 7 and 8 I would want it to be 2 instead of 1 because it is between both 2 and 3.

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy way to do it. Probably, better to ask that as a new question.

Comment: I was wrong about my example. only row 6 should be 2. Turns out one can modify your last line of code with
``` 
dat$result[unique(unlist(Map(seq, inds1, inds2)))] <- table(unlist(Map(seq, inds1, inds2)))
```
To achieve what I wanted.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it,

First convert `NA` to `0`,

```
dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0
```

Then we use ifelse

```
ifelse((dat$id1 == 0 & dat$id2 == 0), 0, 1)
```

In the form of dataframe,

```
dat = cbind(dat, ifelse((dat$id1 == 0 & dat$id2 == 0), 0, 1))
```

Comment: Sorry if my example was not clear. I also the elements inbetween to be 1. For example row 6 contains id1=3 and row 8 contains id2=3 and I therefore want row 7 to be 1 as it is between 6 and 8